# Accessing typedef enum function in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, enums, typedef

I am using to typedef with somevalues in the header. how can i access the enum values and used in the application any one help me.

```
typedef enum{
INFO,PROD,WARN
}INFOS;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
     INFOS infos;
}
-(NSString *)method:(INFOS)infovalue;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [self method:infos];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
- (NSString *) method:(INFOS) infovalue {
NSString *result = nil;

switch(infovalue) {
    case INFO:
        result = @"info";
        break;
    case PROD:
        result = @"prod";
        break;
    case WARN:
        result = @"warn";
        break;

    default:
        result = @"unknown";
}

return result;
}
```

but the method not called after the view load. how can i do it.pls help me

Comment: First of all: your method - (void) method:(INFOS) infovalue returns void, although in the end you try returning a value. Second: what exactly you wanna do, the method is a kind of nonsense

Comment: @SavaMazăre sorry for that mistake now i update my question i want to return the string value

Comment: take a look to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef enum{
   info = 1,
   prod = 2,
   warn = 3
}INFOS;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
     //INFOS infos; you do not need this
}
-(NSString *)method:(INFOS)infovalue;
-(void)viewDidLoad;
{

 [self method:info];

 [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (NSString *) method:(INFOS) infovalue {
NSString *result = nil;

switch(infovalue) {
    case 1:
        result = @"info";
        break;
    case 2:
        result = @"prod";
        break;
    case 3:
        result = @"warn";
        break;

    default:
        result = @"unknown";
}

return result;


 }
```

Comment: look, you have 3 pre-defined values prod, warn and info. when you call your method "method:", you can send it only one of those 3 values. Now, in the method, to check which value was get, you have the switch. the switch can only check for integers, and as you could see, each INFOS type value is assigned an integer. your switch will know which of info/prod/warn value was get. now is your turn to do the proper action in your switch's cases, depending on the value got.

Comment: you can say only like this: [self method:info]; or [self method:prod]; or [self method:warn];

Comment: @SavaMazare Thanks lot..I got the it

Comment: @SavaMazare Sorry,I have one more question i want to use two different type of  typedef enum like this: typedef enum{ PROD,INFO,WARN}INFOS and typedef enum{PROD,WARN}PRODS let i send INFOS as parameter i want to return INFOS enumeration values like PROD,INFO,WARN or i send PRODS as parameter i want the values are like PROD, WARN how can i do this

Comment: I don't see the difference all from PRODS type are in INFOS type. Just use INFOS... or I didn't understand your question...

Comment: ...and rename the method "method:" with another name, as it is confusing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15709/discussion-between-skm-and-sava-mazre)